# Twitter share api doesnt get url with two # signs

Tags: twitter, hash, share

want to share text and url like that:

`test http://one#two#three`

so i try

`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=test&url=http%3A%2F%2Fone%23two%23three`

and get in result only "test" without the url

when in url is only one # sigh is ok
for example

`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=test&url=http%3A%2F%2Fone%23two`

give me 
`test http://one#two`

how to add sec #?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly because it is not [correct syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5) to have more than one `#` in a URL.

What sort of URL are you sharing that needs two?

If you absolutely have to, you can cheat and URL Encode the second `%` into `%25`

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=test&url=http%3A%2F%2Fone%23two%2523two
```

Comment: thanks Terence,

I tweak it different way - instead of filling urls part in twitter call I append the my url to the text field and it works fine.

I will try your way as well.